# Gather POST data in Django, store to session and then redirect to the original page

Tags: ajax, django, django-views, django-sessions

I'm looking to build a webpage based around a changing homepage. It's going to have the user answer questions, with their answers being stored as part of their session (don't want to have to have the user log in). I'd then like to be able to access their answers to show them different content on the homepage on the basis of their answers.

At the moment this is what I've got -

```
## urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from home import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/(?P<choice_id>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail')
```

The user visits the index - clicks on an 'answer' link and I receive a question_id and a choice_id. At the moment, I'm dealing with them like this...

```
## from views.py
class DetailView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'home/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'homepage_object'

    def get_queryset(self):
        question_id, choice_id = self.request.path.replace('/', ':').split(':')[1:3]
        if 'history' not in self.request.session:
            self.request.session['history'] = [{question_id : choice_id}]
            self.request.session.modified = True
        else:
            self.request.session['history'].append({question_id : choice_id})
            self.request.session.modified = True
        product_set = random.sample(Product.objects.all(), 4)
        return product_set
```

So basically I just show the user exactly what they were seeing on the homepage with the bonus of me being able to store their answers. However, it feels like a bit of a hack as they're actually on a completely different page and the URL shows it (and looks messy).

I've investigated redirects following posts but most of them seem to be centred around forms and user authentication and so have special methods surrounding them.

Is there a sensible way of doing this? Is there a neat one-liner that'll handle the parameters I'm interested in and keep the user on the same page. Sort of tempted to go the way of AJAX but don't want to have to start investigating how nicely that plays with Django sessions, which I'm liking using.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went the way of AJAX with this.

All my fears of AJAX and Django Sessions not playing nicely together were allayed and the page now works.

Will leave the question open and unanswered for if anybody else has this problem and finds a non AJAX-less solution.